# Java: Mask formatting strings

Tags: java, string

I would like to know how to format a string into a specified pattern in Java. For example:

```
the source string: 01021234
the desired ouput: 01/02/1234
```

I have followed the MaskFormatter rabit hole, but its proven futile. Could someone clue me in on what function I should be using? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please see Sample code:

```
private static Date prepData(String date, String time) {
    try {
        if (date != null || !date.equals("")) {
            if (date.contains("/")) {
                return new Date(date + " " + time.substring(0, time.indexOf('.')));
            }else{
                MaskFormatter mk = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
                mk.setValidCharacters("1234567890");
                System.out.println(mk.valueToString(date));
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you give more detail? What have you tried with MaskFormatter and why has it proven futile?

Answer (score 0):

go for String.format it has several options

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to format a date use DateFormatter in Java

Comment: Well, although it is a date, its coming in from a log file as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SimpleDateFormat:

http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/

Comment: I have opted to use String.format, however, since I am so new I am not able to answer my own question for another 6 hours. As soon as I'm past that restriction I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I opted to go as I found the MaskFormatter WAY too difficult:

```
private static Date prepData(String date, String time) {
    try {
        if (date != null || !date.equals("")) {
            if (date.contains("/")) {
                return new Date(date + " " + time.substring(0, time.indexOf('.')));
            }else{
                String d = String.format("%s/%s/%s", date.substring(0, 2),date.substring(2, 4),date.substring(4));
                String t = String.format("%s:%s %s", time.substring(0, 2),time.substring(2, 4),time.substring(4));
                return new Date(d + " " + t);
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return null;
}
```